# Why is this prolog program causing infinite recursion?

Tags: prolog, stack-overflow

I am trying to make a simple knowledge base. However, I'm struggling getting the category system to work.

Here is the program so far:

```
subset(tomatoes, fruits).
subset(fruits, food).
subset(X, Z) :- subset(X, Y), subset(Y, Z), not(X==Y), not(Y==Z), not(X==Z).
member(X, Z) :- member(X, Y), subset(Y, Z).
member(t1, tomatoes).
```

Query:

```
member(t1,tomatoes).
ERROR: Out of local stack
   Exception: (1,765,494) member(t1, _G28504) ? abort
% Execution Aborted
```

Comment: I'm a bit rusty on Prolog, but have you tried putting your facts first?  As in, moving member(t1, tomatoes) up above the recursive rules?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You encountered the phenomenon called *left recursion*. Solving the goal `subset(X, Z)` is reduced to solving the goal `subset(X, Y)` with a new unbound variable `Y` and this leads to solving the same goal `subset(X, Z)` etc, ad infinitum. Left recursions should be avoided.

The usual approach is to dinstinguish between basic facts and rules for transitive closures. You could try:

```
subset1(tomatoes, fruits).
subset1(fruits, food).

subset(X, Y) :- subset1(X, Y).
subset(X, Z) :- subset1(X, Y), subset(Y, Z).

member1(t1, tomatoes).
member1(t2, tomatoes).

member(X, Y) :- member1(X, Y).
member(X, Z) :- member1(X, Y), subset(Y, Z).

?- member(t1, food).       ===> TRUE
```

There is no left recursion in this formulation. First a direct fact is tried that can terminate the recursion. Only if there is no fact, a recursive call is performed.